# RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 3, 3, 3], expected input[1, 4, 160, 40] to have 3 channels, but got 4 channels instead

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I am trying to use a pre-trained model. Here's where the problem occurs

Isn't the model supposed to take in a simple colored image? Why is it expecting a 4-dimensional input?

The `eval()` method is:

```
def eval(file):
    image = io.imread(file)
    plt.imshow(image)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (160,40)).transpose((2,1,0))
    output = model(torch.tensor(image[np.newaxis,...]).float())[0].squeeze().detach().numpy()
    return decode_prob(output)
```

And the output of `eval('image.png')` :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-0b951c2596f8> in <module>()
----> 1 eval('/content/image.png')

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in _conv_forward(self, input, weight)
    344                             _pair(0), self.dilation, self.groups)
    345         return F.conv2d(input, weight, self.bias, self.stride,
--> 346                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    347 
    348     def forward(self, input):

RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 3, 3, 3], expected input[1, 4, 160, 40] to have 3 channels, but got 4 channels instead
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image you are loading is a 4 channel Image.
You can read it with cv2 and convert it to 3 channel RGB image as

```py
def eval(file):
    image = cv2.imread(file)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGB)
    plt.imshow(image)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (160,40)).transpose((2,1,0))
    output = model(torch.tensor(image[np.newaxis,...]).float())[0].squeeze().detach().numpy()
    return decode_prob(output)
```

Comment: I was trying that, but it show error: OSError: Cannot understand given URI: array([[[23, 28, 56],
        [25, 30, 57],
        [24, ....

Comment: I think you just passed the image to imread. Make sure you are doing it right. Updated the code to reflect it in your function

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I did not realize. I take advantage of asking: do you know any OCR to read patent plates?

Comment: Nope. Latest Teserract  is the best of opensource. That's what we use for our product at work. Or try google's paid version if that's a feasible option. But nothing specialized for this application that I know of.